# Amazon example transfermanager code does not compile

Tags: c++, awss3transfermanager

I have not been able to find a working sample of AWS C++ SDK transfer manager. The AWS provided example fails to compile using GCC 7.0.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 It has many errors, the first of which is that there is no default constructor for TransferManagerConfiguration.

I'm actually trying to find some way to get an object larger than 2GB with the C++ SDK. I can do so in other languages. I'm trying to get transfer manager to work to see if that will get around it. But I cannot get the Amazon-provided sample code to build on either Windows or Linux. The sample is from their "ready for production blog post.

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/transfer/TransferManager.h>

static const char* ALLOC_TAG = "main";

int main()
{
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);

    auto s3Client = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::S3::S3Client>(ALLOC_TAG);
    Aws::Transfer::TransferManagerConfiguration transferConfig;
    transferConfig.s3Client = s3Client;

    transferConfig.transferStatusUpdatedCallback =
        [](const TransferManager*, const TransferHandle& handle)
    { std::cout << "Transfer Status = " <<   static_cast(handle.GetStatus()) << "\n"; }

        transferConfig.uploadProgressCallback =
        [](const TransferManager*, const TransferHandle& handle)
    { std::cout << "Upload Progress: " << handle.GetBytesTransferred() << " of "
        << handle.GetBytesTotalSize() << " bytes\n"; };

    transferConfig.downloadProgressCallback =
        [](const TransferManager*, const TransferHandle& handle)
    { std::cout << "Download Progress: " << handle.GetBytesTransferred() << " of "
        << handle.GetBytesTotalSize() << " bytes\n"; };

    Aws::Transfer::TransferManager transferManager(transferConfig);
    auto transferHandle = transferManager.UploadFile("/user/aws/giantFile",
        "aws_cpp_ga", "giantFile",
        "text/plain", Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::String>());
    transferHandle.WaitUntilFinished();

    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like it to build and upload a file.

Comment: Presumably a versioning issue. It's easy enough to find documentation that says TransferManagerConfiguration does have a default ctor, and also to find documentation that says it doesn't. Maybe this [unit test code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/aws-cpp-sdk-transfer-tests/TransferTests.cpp) which uses a non-default TransferManagerConfiguration ctor will help.

Comment: If you want to handle 2GB or more then I would prefer to build 64 bit code. 32 bit code should theoretically be able to address upto 4 GB but practically it's usually significantly lower (due to OS, reserved address ranges, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

This is my go-to template. It's really annoying Aws forgets to update its tutorials.

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/transfer/TransferManager.h>

static const char *ALLOC_TAG = "main";

/*
 * referenced from:
 * https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/aws-cpp-sdk-transfer-tests/TransferTests.cpp
 */

int main() {
  Aws::SDKOptions options;
  // for debug purpose since transfer mngr fails silently.
  options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Info;
  Aws::InitAPI(options);

  Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
  clientConfiguration.endpointOverride = "https//store-test.example.com";
  clientConfiguration.region = "store-test";

  using namespace Aws::Transfer;
  using namespace Aws::Utils;

  auto s3Client = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::S3::S3Client>(ALLOC_TAG, clientConfiguration);
  auto thread_executor =
      Aws::MakeShared<Threading::PooledThreadExecutor>(ALLOC_TAG, 4);

  Aws::Transfer::TransferManagerConfiguration transferConfig(
      thread_executor.get());
  transferConfig.s3Client = s3Client;

  transferConfig.transferStatusUpdatedCallback =
      [](const TransferManager *,
         const std::shared_ptr<const TransferHandle> &handle) {
        std::cout << "Transfer Status = "
                  << static_cast<int>(handle->GetStatus()) << "\n";
      };

  transferConfig.uploadProgressCallback =
      [](const TransferManager *,
         const std::shared_ptr<const TransferHandle> &handle) {
        std::cout << "Upload Progress: " << handle->GetBytesTransferred()
                  << " of " << handle->GetBytesTotalSize() << " bytes\n";
      };

  auto transferManager = TransferManager::Create(transferConfig);
  auto transferHandle = transferManager->UploadFile(
      "/user/aws/giantFile", "aws_cpp_ga", "giantFile", "text/plain",
      Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::String>());

  transferHandle->WaitUntilFinished();
  /* you may need to reset the thread pool before shutdown API */
  thread_executor.reset();
  Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Izana - that got me past my roadblock. I appreciate your answering. I did need to change this line so the default credentials would be used:
    auto s3Client Aws::MakeShared<Aws::S3::S3Client(ALLOC_TAG,clientConfiguration);.  

I do have one remaining issue: After a successful transfer, on return, I get an exception thrown fail with a mutex allocation  in xmtx.cpp (Visual Studio 2019 runtime). Is there something I need to do to cleanup the TransferManager or TransferHandle before the ShutdownAPI? (the fail happens when stepping out of the main function).

Comment: I don't have this issue on my mac machine. How about reset the thread_executor before shutdown API?

Comment: I'll try that. Also, it only happens on upload - downloads from AWS have no such problem. I'll also test on Linux. Thanks